# Importing 2008 Visual Studio Project (3.5 .NET) into Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to continue a project (outlook addin, Visual Basic) which was done with Visual Studios 2008. When i import this in Visual Studios 2013 it instantly starts converting it into a newer Framework which results in a lot of errors and necessary manual changes.

I tried to change the target Framework in the Project Options afterwards but im just getting an error.

Im just wondering if there is any way to import this project instantly as a 3.5.NET project?

Greetings

Comment: What errors do you get? I doubt any of the errors are actually issues with the downward compatibility of .NET 4.5.

Comment: When i try to publish the project i get some very large error: "unexpected error in the FindRibbon Task...". But it runs through tough. If i start the setup there is a Exception with the manifest: "Exception reading manifest from file://.... the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. Additionally if i just try to test the addin, outlook is starting but nothing project dependant shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Had to delete the `<Assembly: SecurityTransparent()>` Attribute. Apparently Visual Studios doesnt delete it.